# When error occurs during run session in QTP, Error Popup is not displayed

Tags: qtp

When any syntax or object not found error occurs during run session in QTP, it is not displaying the Error Popup with the options 'Skip'/'Re-Run'/'Debug', Instead the test script is getting failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings. Open the "File" -> "Settings" menu, then the "Run" section. Beside the text "When error occurs during run session", make sure **pop up message box** is selected instead of anything else. (I'm looking at UFT 11.53 right now though, it might be slightly different in your version of QTP.)

Otherwise, **On Error Resume Next** has probably been activated somewhere in the code. Search for it. Once found you need to determine if it's there for a reason. If so, add **On Error GoTo 0** at the first line error skipping is not needed. If it isn't needed, remove it.

Comment: Even after removing "On Error Resume Next" from the code and change the "When error occurs during run session" settings to "pop up message box" , UFT is not displaying the dialog box when error occurs.